# Как реализовать данный код, чтобы он выполнялся при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L1byuL8j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // тут ваш код
});
```